# How do I add a form in an Excel sheet?

Tags: excel

How can I add an input form in an Excel sheet. I want to insert values into an Excel cell using the form.

Comment: Raj, you are killing me.  Please accept some answers.  That is how people let other know what "The Answer" is, gives the posting user some reputation to let others know that they know what they are talking about, and generally makes you look a little more worth their while.  Nobody likes answering questions that they are relatively certain will not be voted or marked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ALT+F11 starts the VBA editor in Excel.  In there you can create UserForms (Insert | UserForm) which you can bind into their own modules or attach to worksheets.

I suggest you look at the Excel help or MSDN for details of what you can do with UserForms.  There are also a lot of VBA tutorials on the web for exactly this sort of thing.  Google is your friend.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

There is a quick and dirty method of creating simple forms in Excel. No VBA is required.

First, create a table with the basic format that you want.

E.g.

```
    A    B    C
1   Name Age  Favourite Animal
2   Jane 11   Horse
```

Select the range, and then select Data | Form. (This is in Excel 2003.)

It will open up a simple form that allows navigation, creation, deletion, and searching.

Answer (score 2):

@Oddthinking,

Cool trick.  Never knew it existed.  I had to do a little looking, but you can do it in Excel 2007 as well.

1. Click the Office button, select Excel Options, go to the Customize tab
2. Select 'Commands Not in the Ribbon' from the 'Choose commands from' drop down
3. Find 'Form' in the list and click Add, then click OK

At this point, the Forms command will show up on the Quick Access toolbar, next to the Save and Undo/Redo icons.

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate the form toolbar.
Of course, IIRC, the form must be handled by VBA code.