# Get a code of Excel form

Tags: excel, vba

After googling on Excel forms, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327361/how-do-i-add-a-form-in-an-excel-sheet) question. And although question is not well asked, I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/331494/1128699) great.

I tried it with my data, and excel really provides me with fairly good form. But I want to make some modification to it (e.g. add a direct search field). So my question is: Is there a way to get VBA code of this form (Excel automated form), or to modify it in some other way?

And also how can I make this form be called from button, so that I don't have to every time create a new form. (I could do that if I would have its VBA code.)

If anyone knows way to accomplish this, I would be grateful. Thank you for any suggestions and your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to call that data form use the followings:

```
Range("A1").Select    'assuming there is any cell of your data
ActiveSheet.ShowDataForm
```

I don't think you can change or modify that form in any way.